# Popup with OpenLayers 6.8.1 for getFeatureInfo

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to create a popup when you click with information about the layer in an attribute table with a content.ftl, containing an image.

I saw that OpenLayers 2 has a simple popup function with

```
  popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("chicken",
               new OpenLayers.LonLat(5,40),
               new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
               "example popup",
               true);
map.addPopup(popup);
```

For example. Does OpenLayers 6.8.1 have a simple popup function with getFeatureInfo and singleclick function? Or is it possible to switch my library to OpenLayers 2?

Comment: OL6 example https://codesandbox.io/s/popup-forked-jm19g?file=/main.js using a combination of the methods in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html and https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html

Comment: @Mike Thank you, this solution worked! I adjusted it so it would work with a proxy, and now it displays my attributes from the GeoServer layer.